# Question on integral values of a quadratic

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question is: Find the integral values of *a* for which $x^2-(a+10)x + 10a +1 =0 $ has integral roots.

For a quadratic to have integral roots, it's D has to be a perfect square.

The discriminant(D) = $a^2-20a+96$
For a quadratic to be a perfect square, its D has to equal zero. But here, $D = 400-384$ which is not equal to zero. I'm stuck now.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Let $a^2-20a+96=(a-b)^2$

$$\iff2a(b-10)+96=b^2$$

Clearly, $b$ must be even $=2c$(say)

$$2a(2c-10)+96=4c^2\iff a(c-5)+24=c^2\iff a=\dfrac{c^2-24}{c-5}=c+5+\dfrac1{c-5}$$

So, $c-5$ must divide $1\implies c-5=\pm1$

---

Alternatively, let $$a^2-20a+96=c^2$$

$$(a-10)^2-c^2=4$$

$$(a-10-c)(a-10+c)=4$$